# Controlling marker visibility in real-time via Firebase

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I have students showing in the map and each one has `show` boolean value. I'm using this value to determine if the marker should show or not on the map using `setVisible()` method.!

I have a switch button that shows and hide the marker by updating the `show` value in the real-time database, and it doesn't always work.

The problem is, when the value is set to `false` => the markers don't hide!!, but when it becomes `true` they show up !? the only way for the markes to hide is if I close the map and then open it again which of course is not what anyone want.!

Any suggestion.!?

---

**How I show the markers**

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference refStudents = database.getReference("Students");
    refStudents.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {

       LatLng latLng = new LatLng(snapshot.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getLat(), 
       snapshot.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getLang());
       boolean show = snapshot.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).isShow();

    studentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title(item.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getName() + "")
            .snippet(item.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getSection() + "")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
             getMarkerBitmapFromView(item.getValue(TestUserStudent.class)
              .getImg(), R.drawable.redMarker))));

       if (show) {
      studentMarker.setVisible(true);
      }else {
      studentMarker.setVisible(false);
       }

      }

      @Override
      public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
      }
    });
```

---

**How I update the markers**

```
private void updateShowing(final boolean isShow) {

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
              ds.child("show").getRef().setValue(isShow);
            }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.i( "onCancelled: ", error.getDetails() +"\n "+ error.getMessage());
          }
        });
    }
```

---

**TestUserStudent.class**

```
public class TestUserStudent {

  boolean show;
  //other attributes 

  public boolean isShow() { return show; }
  public void setShow(boolean show) { this.show = show; }

 //other setters & getters
 }
```

---

**Firebase rtd**

[image]

Comment: while updating, how you are checking which student marker to update?

Comment: I'm not, I want them all to update..! and it did when i click the switch button the values in all the children in the database gets updated correctly..!

Comment: so whats the issue if it doing already?

Comment: the issue on the UI or reading the values .. let's assume all the students has isShow `false` when opening the map. when I change it true all the students markers show normally but if I change it back to `false` they don't hide even though the value is change to false. If I close the map and open it again they won't show because it's false, but I want this to happen in real time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to remove markers before updating markers.Create a `ArrayList` to save `Markers` references.

```
ArrayList<Marker> studentMarkersList=new ArrayList();
```

Then use list like this:

```
@Override
      public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {

       LatLng latLng = new LatLng(snapshot.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getLat(), 
       snapshot.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getLang());
       boolean show = snapshot.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).isShow();

       if(show)
        {
             studentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title(item.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getName() + "")
            .snippet(item.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getSection() + "")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
             getMarkerBitmapFromView(item.getValue(TestUserStudent.class)
              .getImg(), R.drawable.redMarker))));
             studentMarkersList.add(studentMarker);
        }



      }
```

Then define a method to remove markers:

```
private void removeStudentMarkers()
            {
                for(int i=0;i<studentMakersList.size();i++)
                {
                    studentMarkersList.get(i).remove();
                }
            }
```

At last do this:

```
private void updateShowing(final boolean isShow) {

    removeStudentMarkers();

    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Students")
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
              ds.child("show").getRef().setValue(isShow);
            }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.i( "onCancelled: ", error.getDetails() +"\n "+ error.getMessage());
          }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I can't use `googleMap.clear()` because it clears everything and I have other markers that are fixed and I don't want them to be gone.!

Comment: glad to help dear

Comment: let's say I wanted one marker from that list to be hidden when some action accrued to it. I managed to update its isShow value in the database correctly using its key which I stored in a list. then i removed that marker from the list. but it didn't hide in real-time.! I had to close the map and open it again to refresh the markers.! any suggestions.?

Comment: @AlaaAbuZarifa you can post another question

Comment: I did, it's here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168472/hiding-just-one-marker-from-a-list-isnt-working

Answer (score 0):

Just do not create the marker when `show == false` on your `onChildChanged` method :

```
if (show) {
    studentMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(latLng)
    .title(item.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getName() + "")
    .snippet(item.getValue(TestUserStudent.class).getSection() + "")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap( getMarkerBitmapFromView(item.getValue(TestUserStudent.class) .getImg(), R.drawable.redMarker))));
}
```

Comment: still the same thing!