# How to restart google map fragment manually

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

When the map fragment opens for the first time it calls `onMapReady` and it adds a marker in there and zooms towards with animation.

I want if user click a button on the map, the map will restart as if its open like the begining with zoom and whatnot.

I tried using the method below which I call when I click the button, but it only recreate the map but it didn't call `onMapReady` because it didn't add maker or anything.!

```
public void reLoadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    Fragment currentFragment = fragment;
    if (currentFragment instanceof MapTransportFragment_BusDriver) {
      FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      fragTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
      fragTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
      fragTransaction.commit();
    }
  }
```

**Edit #1**

I call the method using all three ways belowa and it gives me the same error.

```
 /*1*/ reLoadFragment(this);

 /*2*/ reLoadFragment(MyMap.this);

 /*3*/ reLoadFragment(new MyMap()); // MyMap is the name of the current fragment.
```

Comment: onMapReady called only once during life of an App. You can't restart map until you restart app. Map instance is controlled by Google Play Service process but not by your app process

Comment: @NileshRathod the accepted answer there didn't work!

Comment: @ZaidMirza ...but it still a fragment, I guess there should be something that can be done about restarting a fragment!

Comment: Map works based on Singleton pattern. fragment could be restarted but not map.

Comment: so there's no hope ..! I wanted this coz I thought it would be a workaround for an issue that I'm having..maybe you could give it a look and I'd be appreciated it a lot. thanks | https://stackoverflow.com/q/49093890/1877061

Comment: Use map.clear(). Zoom to where you need it..

Answer (score 0):

However, If you want just to restart your fragment it means you want to create new fragment. calling `detach` and `attach` doesn't destroy fragment.So try below code

```
 public void reLoadFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        Fragment currentFragment = fragment;
        if (currentFragment instanceof MapTransportFragment_BusDriver) {
          FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          fragTransaction.replace(R.id.YourFragmentContainer,currentFragment,"TAG");

          fragTransaction.commit();
        }

  }
```

Comment: gives me this error, I made sure it the correct container id. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment`

Comment: can you show me code where you are calling reLoadFragment